# How to have robocopy search subdirectories inside of source folder for the files to move?

Tags: robocopy

I am using a recording program to record clips of games, and the program I am using records full sessions with the full session recording files being saved MKV files in my `F:\Videos\Clips` folder. After editing/cutting the full session recordings into clips of the moments I want to save, it saves them as `.mp4` files.

However, it also sorts all my full session recordings and edited clips by the specific game, so for example recording "Escape From Tarkov", the recordings/edits will be in `F:\Videos\Clips\EscapeFromTarkov`, and for "League of Legends" they will be in `F:\Videos\Clips\LeagueOfLegends`.

This is my current batch file I have to move the edited clips (with task manager running it every time I start my pc/whenever my pc has been on for 4 hours+):

```
(at symbol)Echo Off
Set "source=F:\Videos\Clips"
Set "destination=F:\Videos\Cut Clips"
%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe "%source%" "%destination%" "*.mp4" /Mov
Exit /B
```

Now the issue is that this isn't moving the `.mp4` files as they are all inside different sub-directories which are inside of the parent folder which is F:\Videos\Clips.

How can I get it to look inside each of the sub-directories that are inside `F:\Videos\Clips` for the `.mp4` files to move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the copy option `/s` to copy from subdirectories. The file pattern might also be an issue if you're using double quotes. Try the following:

```
@Echo Off
Set "source=F:\Videos\Clips"
Set "destination=F:\Videos\Cut Clips"
robocopy.exe "%source%" "%destination%" *.mp4 /Mov /s
Exit /B
```

Comment: the double quote marks on the set lines should not be around the variable names. ie. you should have set source="F:\Video\Clips" instead of set "source=F:\Video\Clips"

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now! Don't know how I missed such a simple fix haha. I appreciate the help!